# Unity pulldown menu highlight shadow stuck permanently on after selecting Help and Tools in Firefox

Tags: unity, firefox

I was browsing Firefox, and I selected [the Help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXeE7.png) and [Tools pulldown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gc5Ac.png) menus in quick succession, but since I moved the mouse to Tools before Help fully loaded (race conditon?), the Unity highlight shadow that surrounded the pulldown menu (before it fully expanded to width) [got stuck on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrJ3m.png) somehow. It persists above all other windows, it's not clickable, not selectable, and blocks clicks to whatever is behind it.

What is this? How do I kill it, preferably without logging out and back in?

I have restarted Firefox already. 
[Fullscreen text editor screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m40Bj.png) to show the thing more clearly. The only thing that gets "in front of" this is the Dash, but you can still see a blurred rendition of the stuck highlight shadow zombie lurking "behind" the Dash.
(Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, but this issue may not be version-specific)

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out with xwininfo that this artefact was the responsibility of `unity-panel-service`:

```
$ xwininfo

xwininfo: Please select the window about which you
          would like information by clicking the
          mouse in that window.

xwininfo: Window id: 0x10c2495 "unity-panel-service"

  Absolute upper-left X:  387
  Absolute upper-left Y:  24
  Relative upper-left X:  387
  Relative upper-left Y:  24
  Width: 42
  Height: 200
  Depth: 32
  Visual: 0x5e
  Visual Class: TrueColor
  Border width: 0
  Class: InputOutput
  Colormap: 0x100000a (not installed)
  Bit Gravity State: NorthWestGravity
  Window Gravity State: NorthWestGravity
  Backing Store State: NotUseful
  Save Under State: yes
  Map State: IsViewable
  Override Redirect State: yes
  Corners:  +387+24  -595+24  -595-544  +387-544
  -geometry 42x200+387+24
```

I then did `pgrep unity-panel` (to check it was running) and `pkill unity-panel` (to relaunch it), and that fixed it; it's gone now.

That said, I am not averse to hearing more information on what caused this weird bug. Does it still make sense to report it somewhere else, despite 16.04 LTS being an older version and despite Ubuntu moving away from Unity?